# OpenID equivalence

Tags: openid

Has there been discussion around how to resolve equivalent openids? Meaning,
I personally have 8 openid providers and the number is sure to grow. Have
you discussed a way to make them equivalent during authentication?

I put together a solution based on the rel="me" link graph. Agree or
disagree?

http://blog.paulisageek.com/2009/06/equivalent-openids.html

Comment: I can't see how this is a real question and not a way to publicise your "solution". Frankly if you have 8 identities you deserve the pain of keeping them in sync, especially when delegation is there to look after you should your main provider vanish.

Comment: Do you not have a google, yahoo, twitter, blogspot, etc. account? They are all openid providers. I know I have this exact problem with my multiple emails, and would like to solve it this time around with openid identity.

Comment: Well for starters twitter doesn't give you an openid account, they are not a provider.

The problem here is not with OpenID, but with companies wanting to be your sole identity. Google, Yahoo, even MS with their beta OpenID/Live ID support are providers but won't accept anyone else's. Even a loose federation "standard" won't solve this, it's cultural not technological.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about adding the following to the home page on your domain, and using your domain as your OpenID?

```
<link rel="openid.server" href="..." />
<link rel="openid.delegate" href="..." />
<link rel="openid2.local_id" href="..." />
<link rel="openid2.provider" href="..." />
```

Then when you want to change provider, you just update the information here.

Comment: I don't think most people do this, let alone have a domain. The majority of people I know that use openid use the direct endpoint given by their provider.

But yes, for me, that will work; I just want to explore solving it for the unwashed masses. :)

Answer (score 1):

An OpenID Identifier merely allows you to prove you own some identifier (typically a URL).  If you control many URLs, it only makes sense to activate as many of them as OpenID Identifiers as you want to maintain distinct identities for.

So no, I'd be against this rel="me" approach.  Besides the fact that HTML discovery is about to be deprecated in OpenID anyway since it's difficult to make secure and resilient against the many forms of HTML there are.